# Protrusion or Extrusion?

Tags: back, spine, dorsal-upper-back-side

[image]Here is an MRI picture of someone who suffers from a backache. Does any one know that his problem is disk extrusion or disk protrusion? 
It does not seems to be a disk extrusion, yes?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This has all the signs of indirectly asking for medical advice, but I'd like to imagine this is a healthcare provider asking colleagues to discuss the difference between protrusion or extrusion in this case, so because the answer is good, I'm voting to keep it.  But please do not take answers as medical advice.  If this is you or someone you know, have a doctor look at it.

Answer (score 1):

To me it appears like an extrusion, have a close look at this.
[image]
The aperture of the disk material that is outside its confined space is larger than the the width of its normal boundaries. Since, it's very minor I still doubt to completely categorize it.

I read an article that explains the difference between "**disk protrusion & extrusion**": here is the [**link to it.**](http://blog.medivisuals.com/blogmedivisualscom/bid/71959/Protrusions-Versus-Extrusions-Intervertebral-Disc-Pathology-Part-3-of-3)